# joining multiple tables with filter by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

i got 3 tables..how do i join these tables with filter by date on each table

MainTbl

```
 id    accnt   amount    date
---------------------------------
  1      xxx     10.00   1/1/2016
  2      yyy     20.00   1/1/2016
  3      zzz     30.00   1/1/2016
```

SupplyTbl - this table would add the value of supply to the amount in the MainTbl

```
  id   accnt    supply   date
-------------------------------
   1     xxx     5.00     1/10/2016
   1     xxx     5.00     2/14/2016
   2     yyy    10.00     1/20/2016
```

IssuedTbl

```
  id   accnt    issued   dateIssue
------------------------------------------
   1     xxx    5.00      1/10/2016
   1     xxx    5.00      2/14/2016
   2     yyy   10.00      2/15/2016
```

now i want to join these tables..with date range..if i filter the date to `JANUARY` it would result something like this

```
  id   accnt  amount   issued
 -----------------------------
  1     xxx    15.00    5.00
  2     yyy    30.00    0.00
  3     zzz    30.00    0.00
```

and when i filter to `FEBRUARY`..it will combine both from `JANUARY` to `FEBRUARY`

```
 id   accnt  amount   issued
 -----------------------------
  1     xxx    20.00   10.00
  2     yyy    40.00   10.00
  3     zzz    30.00    0.00
```

i'm struggling with this since the other night..glad with any help..tnx in advance :)

Comment: The nature of your desired join is unclear.  Does `SupplyTbl` have anything to do with it?

Comment: The nature of the filter condition you want is also unclear.  Which of your dates do you intend to compare against the filter?  Also, do you intend to filter out dates from previous years, if any were present?

Comment: the values of supply in supplyTbl will add to the amount in MainTbl..according to their ID..sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT M.id, 
       M.accnt, 
       amount = M.amount + Isnull(s.supply, 0), 
       issued = Isnull(I.issued, 0) 
FROM   maintbl M 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, 
                               Sum(supply) AS supply 
                        FROM   supplytbl 
                        WHERE  Month(dates) = 1  -- Month filter for Jan - feb Month(dates) in (1,2)
                        GROUP  BY id) S 
                    ON s.id = M.id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, 
                               Sum(issued) AS issued 
                        FROM   issuedtbl 
                        WHERE  Month(dateissue) = 1 -- Month filter
                        GROUP  BY id) I 
                    ON I.id = M.id
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab26c/4)

Comment: i'll try this one out mate..tnx

Comment: hmmm..how can we do this in query in a views ? in filter the date using a variable ? like `WHERE  Month(dateissue) = textbox.text` ?